# Using Regex for custom validators that prevents URL's being entered in contact form/inputs

Tags: regex, model-view-controller

I have an MVC project with a contact form. Im trying to prevent links being added into the message box, either `http`, `https` or `www` by using a custom validator.

I have done the following to prevent links being added:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^/(?!http|https|www)([a-z0-9]+)$", ErrorMessage ="You cannot insert links into the message")]
[Required (ErrorMessage = "Your message cannot be left blank")]
public string inputMessage
{
    get; set;
}
```

but this only sort of works. It prevent links if the begining of the message starts either of those, but if the message were to contain a message FOLLOWED by a link, it doesn't work

I've used https://regexr.com/ to try some things out, but because I don't know regex very well, all attempts have failed.

I think I also discovered that punctuation wasnt allowed with the regex above, so with the first problem in mind, I also added some common punctuation to be allowed `^(?!http|https|www)([A-Za-z0-9 .,!?£%&])\w+$` but this doesnt seem to do the trick.

How do I allow messages to pass the validation, while a link (that starts with `http`, `https` or `www`) anywhere in the message is not allowed.

Some examples:

> Hi. I was just wondering if blah blah blah? Thanks!

Should pass validation

> Hi. I was just wondering if blah blah blah? The link is www.google.com. Thanks!

Should not pass validation

> www.google.com

Should not pass validation

EDIT: P.S It doesnt need to check if it's a valid URL, just if the input anywhere contains http,https or www. Apart from that it should pass validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
^((?!(www|http)).)*$
```

From the start of the string does a greedy negative lookbehind looking for something different from **http** or **www** then the end of the string.

Comment: Works a charm. Thank you